# Could not fetch model of type 'Eclipseproject' using gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14-bin.zip'

Tags: java, gradle, sts

I get this error in sts when I try to import an existing gradle project. Not able to see the gradle tasks.

I have tried downloading the gradle zip files and placing them in the gradle folder. That didnt work as well.

I have also tried creating new workspace and see if it resolves due to some metadata issue. That didnt work as well.

I have tried clearing my gradle cache and building the project again but didnt resolve it.

Any suggestions would be helpful.